# Magento 2 : my custom menu is not displayed in admin panel

Tags: magento2, theme, custom, menu, custom-menu

I was creating a custom menu in Magento 2 but this was not being shown!

file location:
`Magento2Root/app/code/Cloudways/Adminmenu/registration.php`

other files:`module.xml`

third file: `menu.xml`
[image]

screenshot of my code

Comment: Post your code for `menu.xml` and provide path where you have created it.

Comment: path menu.xml [ Magento2Root/app/code/Cloudways/Adminmenu/menu.xml ] and code show my screen shot

Answer (score 1):

Make sure that your module.xml is in the path - `Magento2Root/app/code/Cloudways/Adminmenu/etc` and menu.xml is in the path - `Magento2Root/app/code/Cloudways/Adminmenu/etc/adminhtml`

If this doesn't help then edit your question and add content of all the 3 files so that People can answer that.

Answer (score 1):

You have to create ACL acl.xml

- `app/code/Cloudways/Adminmenu/etc/acl.xml`

Also menu.xml should be under

- `app/code/Cloudways/Adminmenu/etc/adminhtml/menu.xml`

Answer (score 1):

Please verify that the path of **`menu.xml`** should be **`app/code/Cloudways/Adminmenu/etc/adminhtml/menu.xml`**.

Apart from that, if you are checking the menu item from a user with restricted permission role, then you must specify **`acl.xml`** in your module under **`app/code/Cloudways/Adminmenu/etc/acl.xml`**.

**Edit:** If you are having trouble in finding the cause of issue, then retry with the steps below:

> **Step 1:** Create app/code/Stack/Adminmenu/registration.php and put the following content

```
<?php
\Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::register(
    \Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::MODULE,
    'Stack_Adminmenu',
    __DIR__
);
```

> **Step 2:** Create app/code/Stack/Adminmenu/etc/module.xml and put the following code

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Module/etc/module.xsd">
    <module name="Stack_Adminmenu" setup_version="0.1.0">
    </module>
</config>
```

> **Step 3:** Create app/code/Stack/Adminmenu/etc/adminhtml/menu.xml and put the following code

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="../../../Backend/etc/menu.xsd">
    <menu>
        <add id="Stack_Adminmenu::first_level_demo"
             title="Admin Menu"
             module="Stack_Adminmenu"
             sortOrder="20"
             resource="Magento_Backend::content"
        />
        <add id="Stack_Adminmenu::second_level_demo"
             title="Sub Menu"
             module="Stack_Adminmenu"
             sortOrder="1"
             action="menuitem/index/index"
             parent="Stack_Adminmenu::first_level_demo"
             resource="Magento_Backend::content"
        />
    </menu>
</config>
```

Remember to define and create the controller class for the action where you are redirecting on clicking on the menu item.